# android go back to custom fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am implementing three tabs using **ActionBarSherLock** say 1|2|3 in my main Activity, and all three tabs extends fragments with swipe behavior say fragmentA | fragmentB | fragmentC, I have an **onCreateOptionsMenu** at my 4th activity containing three items,

My Question is :
If i click on onCreateOptionsMenu item, App should switch to the corresponding fragment..
Like, if i click on itemA, it shoud move to 1st tab, if itemB then 2nd, if itemC then 3rd

Is that possible? or i can only move within fragments, using

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack()
```

while,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisContext, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
startActivity(intent);
```

this will only switch back to 1st tab,
Please help..